# reading json into django error

Tags: json, ajax, django

I'm passing a context variable, x, into a template from a Djano view. It is a list of strings

```
x = ['Braselton', 'Buford']
```

Then I am using an ajax function to pass that variable back to a django view. The problem is when I retrieve that variable in a python view with the following code:

```
new_x = request.GET['x']
print(new_x)
```

I see the following:

```
[&#39;Braselton&#39;, &#39;Buford&#39;]
```

I've tried json.loads(request.GET['x']) and I keep getting the following error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: it's not a json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unescape those characters, there are lots of ways to do it..
[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) for more info

```
import html.parser
import json

variable = "[&#39;Braselton&#39;, &#39;Buford&#39;]"
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
new_variable = parser.unescape(variable)
new_variable = json.loads(parser.unescape(new_variable).replace("'",'"')) # replace single quote
>>> ['Braselton', 'Buford'] # Type List
```

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python escaping the HTML elements. Note that it's not JSON.

to unescape you have to use HTML module.

```
import html
y = html.unenscape(new_x)
print(y) # output is ['Braselton', 'Buford']
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the variable as safe.

`'{{ x | safe }}'`